# Fail to install Go 1.2.1 in Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: go, osx-mavericks

I followed the [link](https://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/detail?name=go1.2.1.darwin-amd64-osx10.8.pkg&can=2&q=) to download Go 1.2.1 and tried to install in Mavericks OSX. After installing with the binary package, I cd into the path /usr/local/go and found all the executables. However when I try to run

```
go version
```

it returns

```
$ command not found: go
```

I am not sure what I did wrong but I can't find any resource to it. I also tried to follow this tutorial ([link](http://www.raulmurciano.com/articles/setting-up-go-for-development/)) but still failed. Any help?

Comment: no such file or directory: ./go

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the binaries exist then the directory must not be in your $PATH variable. Per the tutorial you linked, make sure that the following two lines are in your shell profile:

`export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`

Comment: Thank you Evan. I got it now. I wasn't sure about the bashrc variables. I was afraid by writing PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin will erase my other PATH. Turns out this command means add one more path to the PATH variable. Newbies like me can research more about bashrc.

Comment: GOROOT is not even mentioned in the official docs for OS X installation. http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really. @Salvador Dali's answer seems to be the better option now?

Comment: AFAIK the more recent go installers for OSX properly set up your PATH anyways so the entire question has become irrelevant. But yes, as of a while ago you don't need to set GOROOT separately, just setting PATH will be enough.

Answer (score 6):

By default go is installed in `/usr/local/go/bin`. So I fixed the issue by adding this line in bash_profile:

- Edit ~/.bash_profile (for example with `nano ~/.bash_profile`)
- add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`
- save the file, close and open the terminal

and it should work:

```
$ go version
go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, after downloading the archive and running it, Go is by default installed at `/usr/local/go`. The next thing you do is to simply have `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` in your `.profile`. If run into something like `$ command not found: go`, just restart your terminal.

As far as I'm concerned the only mention of

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go1.X
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

is when you're installing a different location other than `/usr/local/go` according to the [official installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install).